# Excel VBA Resize group

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

After executing some deleting rows in VBA, a shape size (group) changes height, but is there a way to do this in VBA rather than in the sheet itself. I've assigned it a Macro (Group1), but I am uncertain what to do next.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just work with the `.Height` property of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set shape properties to Don't move or size with cells

```
Shapes("YourShapename").Placement = xlFreeFloating
```